# Checking multiple attribute values in multiple nodes with XSL

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

the xml is as follows.

```
<MyXml>
<Machine1>
    <SupportedOS>
        <OS1 MajorVersion=1 MinorVersion=2/>
        <OS2 MajorVersion=2 MinorVersion=0/>
        <OS3 MajorVersion=1 MinorVersion=1/>
        <OS4 MajorVersion=2 MinorVersion=1/>
        <OS5 MajorVersion=3 MinorVersion=0/>
     </SupportedOS>
 </Machine1>
 </MyXml>
```

I get the OS version from some source (say MajorVersion=x1 and MinorVersion=x2) inside this XML and Add both the xml programitically. 
The task is to compare the Both the Minor and Major Version of OS and olny if the both of them are same to the source only then copy the Machine node to the transformed xml. 
Let me know the ways to do it. I will try to code myself.

**EDIT**

I want to copy the Machine Node when any one of the OS node has MajorVersion=x1 and MinorVersion=x2.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to copy OS nodes only if `majorVersion=minorversion` or is it something else?

Comment: or better write output XML for the above mentioned input XML.

Comment: I want to copy the the Machine node when any one of the OS node has MajorVersion=x1 and MinorVersion=x2

Comment: please accept the answer if that is the solution you were looking for! that will complete the QnA process.

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind': Appreciate your help, but I made a mistake by not providing the good XML as Dimitre has explained.

Comment: oh! those were parameters to XSLT .. I see.. I didn't understand the question! .. well. Mr. Dimitre is my online teacher :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pMajor" select="1"/>
 <xsl:param name="pMinor" select="2"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "self::*[*/*[@MajorVersion = $pMajor and @MinorVersion = $pMinor]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one is severely malformed and not useful!):

```
<MyXml>
    <Machine1>
        <SupportedOS>
            <OS1 MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="2"/>
            <OS2 MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0"/>
            <OS3 MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"/>
            <OS4 MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="1"/>
            <OS5 MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0"/>
        </SupportedOS>
    </Machine1>
    <Machine2>
        <SupportedOS>
            <OS1 MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="3"/>
            <OS2 MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0"/>
            <OS3 MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"/>
            <OS4 MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="1"/>
            <OS5 MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0"/>
        </SupportedOS>
    </Machine2>
</MyXml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Machine1>
   <SupportedOS>
      <OS1 MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="2"/>
      <OS2 MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0"/>
      <OS3 MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"/>
      <OS4 MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="1"/>
      <OS5 MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0"/>
   </SupportedOS>
</Machine1>
```

Comment: Thanks That was quick work. Seems like I need to grab some more inside into xsl. My apologies for the inconvenience of XML example.

Comment: I didn't understand that the OP expecting values to be supplied by the host program that is params .. :) glad he got the answer.. +1

Answer (score 1):

Compare attributes if they aren't satisfying the condition .. if yes then drop them..

Or else copy them

in the below code, first template copies all nodes,
second template drops OS that is having `MajorVersion not equal to 'x1' and MinorVersion not equal to 'x2'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/MyXml/Machine1/SupportedOS/OS1[@MajorVersion != 'x1' and @MajorVersion!='x2']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually the OS node should not be dropped.I need to copy the complete  machine node as it is.

Comment: @RohitSrivastava, ya rohit check now, if it's working as desired.. and let me know if you need any more help

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind', I think that this code isn't correct -- think about whether you should use `and` or `or`. This is a common mistake when negation is involved.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Well I misunderstood the question.. as I thought, user wants to copy <OSX> node only if it matches, majorversion ="x1"(where x1 is a value!) and minorversion="X2".. So I came up with this code! I understood the requirement after I went through your answer..

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind', This is OK, we are all learning here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/MyXml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//SupportedOS"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SupportedOS">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:if test="@MajorVersion='1' and @MinorVersion='2'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="//Machine1"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```